# powerapp adding changing hyperlinks

Tags: html, hyperlink, powerapps

I am extremely new to Powerapps in fact this is my first project with it. What I want to do is link to a web-page that contains a Knowledge base the body of the hyperlink stays as it is the only thing that changes is the ID it needs to look for.

I have created an app and each article contains its own KB# and i need that KB# to be inserted into the hyperlink. The Text I marked in bold below is the only change in the link. I have created a button that should run the Hyperlink once click and in the OnSelect area I add the below but that is just a static link.

If(Rule2, Launch("https://placeholder.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fkb_view.do%3Fsysparm_article%3D||**KB0010007**||%26sysparm_stack%3D%26sysparm_view%3D")
, Launch("https://placeholder.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fkb_view.do%3Fsysparm_article%3DKB0011526%26sysparm_stack%3D%26sysparm_view%3D")
)

Comment: How you get your KB value?

Comment: Its a value I already have on a share point list, I have roughly 500 articles and each one has a KB number

Answer (score 0):

You should use string concatenation operator **&**

In your case:

```
If(Rule2, 
    Launch("https://placeholder.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fkb_view.do%3Fsysparm_article%3D||KB" & DataSource.column_name & "||%26sysparm_stack%3D%26sysparm_view%3D") , 
    Launch("https://placeholder.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fkb_view.do%3Fsysparm_article%3DKB0011526%26sysparm_stack%3D%26sysparm_view%3D") )
```